# Build with test failure, tag a test as not mandatory

Tags: java, maven, junit

I use Java 8, Maven, (Spring, Mockito), JUnit.

The idea is to know if it is possible to build my application with tests (not skipped and not ignored). And set some as not mandatory.

Maybe there is a annotation like "@FailureWarningOnly" in JUnit or somewhere else?

Requirements:

- I do not want to allow all tests to be in failure, but only these that are not been mandatory for the build.
- I do not want to use @Ignore, because I want to have the info if something goes wrong in the build phase.
- I want also the stacktrace exception of the error with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I am not a big fan of making some tests **have to** be successful while other test **may**.
It is an door opened to make your test more brittle and less helpful and may give bad habits.
In the very most of cases you can use profile or improve the setup of the tests to make their behavior reproducible.

In rare cases where it is not possible, you could make assumptions that whether are not true mean that the next statements of the test should be ignored.
You could make it manually or use a feature of your test framework.

JUnit (4 and 5) provides [`Assumptions`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assumptions.html)  that is :

> a collection of utility methods that support conditional test
>   execution based on assumptions.     In direct contrast to failed
>   assertions, failed assumptions do not result in a test failure;
>   rather, a failed assumption results in a test being aborted.

It looks like to :

```
@Test
public void foo(){
  Assume.assumeTrue(shouldFailTestInThisCase(...));
  // my assertions
  Assert.assertEquals(...);
  Assert.assertEquals(...);
}
```

Comment: Instead of "org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions", I use "org.junit.Assume". That is available by default also.

Comment: Indeed you can. If you use JUnit 4 it makes sense. Otherwise if you use JUnit 5 you should favor the `jupiter` package.